# как перевести число в денежный формат (чтобы 3 числа отделялись пробелом)? в JS

Tags: javascript, строки, функции

как перевести число в денежный формат (чтобы 3 числа отделялись пробелом)? в JS

33333333333333 стало : 333 333 333 333.00

Comment: в базовом числе и в итоговом - разное кол-во цифр

Answer (score 2):

```js
let val = '33333333333333';
function makeMoney(n) {
    return parseFloat(n).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1 ");
}
console.log(makeMoney(val));
```

Comment: parseFloat() - работает и без этого метода.

Если n больше или равно 1e+21, метод toFixed() просто вызывает метод Number.prototype.toString() и возвращает строку в экспоненциальной записи.

Я хочу чтобы вывод был без экспоненциальной записи.

Comment: @Aleksey https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ваш метод не корректно работает:

ввожу в Вашу функцию параметр 777777777777777777777.7
в консоль выдает: 777 777 777 777 777 836 032.00

Comment: Это же денежный формат, ни одно государство в истории пока не выпустило столько денег!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

1) разворачиваем строку, чтобы не полные кластеры оставались слева (пример: 13 453, а не 134 53) 
2) делим на кластеры по 3 
3) переворачиваем обратно, убираем лишние пробелы по бокам, добавляем 00 в конце.

```
function toFormat(str){
    return str.split('').reverse().join('') 
              .match(/\d{0,3}/g).join(' ')
              .split('').reverse().join('').trim()+'.00'
}
```

Comment: Почти работает, только надо в строчку последние `.00` загнать, в кавычки

Comment: оу, это неявные преобразования текста от stack overflow) Да, без ковычек никак))

Answer (score 2):

```js
  const num = 33333333333333;
  console.log(num.toLocaleString('ru-RU')+'.00')
```